# $scope.$watch does not trigger when property updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the watcher statement:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.currentStep , function(newVal , oldVal){
    console.log('Watch: ' ,$scope.currentStep , newVal , oldVal);
});
```

And this is the only code that changes the currentStep property, these functions are triggered on button clicks from the browser:

```
$scope.next = function(valid , event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if(valid){
        $scope.error = false;

         $scope.validate();

        if($scope.currentStep < $scope.totalSteps && !$scope.error){
            $scope.previousStep = $scope.steps.indexOf(true);
            $scope.currentStep = $scope.steps.indexOf(true) + 1;

            $scope.steps[$scope.previousStep] = false;
            $scope.steps[$scope.currentStep] = true;                       
        }
    }
    else {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.errorText ="Please fix your mistakes";
    }
}

$scope.prev = function(){
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.final = false;
    $scope.lastPush --;

    $scope.previousStep = $scope.steps.indexOf(true);
    $scope.currentStep = $scope.steps.indexOf(true) - 1;

    $scope.steps[$scope.previousStep] = false;
    $scope.steps[$scope.currentStep] = true;            
}
```

What I can't understand is no matter that I do the watch only fires on the initialization of the variable. When currentStep updates the watch misses it. I've tried including the third argument with watch to force the watcher to compare by equality and not reference but that doesn't fix the issue. What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems like your problem was solved. Would you mind accepting an answer? Promise I won't be mad if it isn't mine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$watch` expression must be a `String` or a `Function` according to the [`$rootScope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) documentation.

Either of the following should work:

```js
// String
$scope.$watch('currentStep', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('Watch: (current) %o (new) %o (old) %o', $scope.currentStep, newVal, oldVal);
});

// Function
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.currentStep;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('Watch: (current) %o (new) %o (old) %o', $scope.currentStep, newVal, oldVal);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The first argument of `$watch` takes an expression or a function:

```
$scope.$watch('currentStep' , function(newVal , oldVal){
    console.log('Watch: ' ,$scope.currentStep , newVal , oldVal);
});
```

Yes, you could use a function

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ return $scope.currentStep } , function(newVal , oldVal){
    console.log('Watch: ' ,$scope.currentStep , newVal , oldVal);
});
```

but that is obviously more verbose and less desirable.

[$watch docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)